# How can one get a file's path from an ftp server?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, ftp-client

This code gets the file name, but I want to get the file path:

```
 private List <String> checkFiles(FTPClient clients){
    List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
    try {  

        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = clients.listFiles();  
        int length = ftpFiles.length;  
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
          String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();  
          Calendar date = ftpFiles[i].getTimestamp();
          Log.v("aasd", name );
          it.add (name);

        }  
      } catch(Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
      }
    return it ;      
  }
```

Comment: Assuming that your `FTPClient` class is `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`, then the [`listFiles()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles%28%29) method (without any arguments) returns a file listing for the *current working directory*, which can be discovered (if not known) via [`printWorkingDirectory ()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#printWorkingDirectory%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

The path is in the client, not the files.

```
String path = clients.printWorkingDirectory()
```

Comment: i want to path and file     ex. "/file1.txt"

Comment: listFiles will only return the files in the current directory.  The files will all be in the path returned by printWorkingDirectory().

Comment: Do you know what path you need?  Call clients.changeWorkingDirectory(...) to set the path first before listing files.

Comment: For something like /file1.txt the path is / and the file is file1.txt.  The FTP server might not let you put things in / so it's giving you an error when you upload.  You might need something like ~youraccountname/file1.txt.  You have to check the FTP server config for the absolute path if you must use one.  Using just "file1.txt" will work in many cases, because most FTP servers set your working directory to your own folder when you connect.  Also note that uploading is beyond the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 1):

if you want specific path

```
client.changeWorkingDirectory(PathName) eg client.changeWorkingDirectory(folder1/folder2) where folder 2 is inside folder 1
        System.out.println(client.printWorkingDirectory)
```

printWorkingDirectory gives the current path

Answer (score 0):

Below code finds that all files path in any folder on ftp server. 
ftpPath is likes that "ftpserver/folder". List contains paths of all files in folder.

```
public List<string> GetFilesPath(string ftpPath)
        {
        FtpWebRequest request;
        string FtpServerPath = ftpPath;
        List<string> filePathList=new List<string>();

        try
        {
            request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(FtpServerPath)) as FtpWebRequest;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;            
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "ftpPassword");
            request.ConnectionGroupName = "group";
            Stream rs = (Stream)request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs);
            string strList = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lines = null;

            if (strList.Contains("\r\n"))
            {
                lines = strList.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            }
            else if (strList.Contains("\n"))
            {
                lines = strList.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            }

            if (lines == null || lines.Length == 0)
               return null;
            else{

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (line.Length == 0)
                        continue;

                    int x=line.LastIndexOf(' ');
                    int len = line.Length;
                    var str = line.Substring( (x+1), (len - x - 1));
                    var filePath = FtpServerPath+"/"+str;
                    filePathList.Add(filePath);
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```